# .NET: How do I determine if an object is a COM object?

Tags: .net, com

How do I determine if an object is a COM object? I need to call Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject on all COM objects in an array of type Object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Marshal.IsComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.iscomobject.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

```
typeof(myObject).IsCOMObject
```

or

```
instanceOfMyObject.GetType().IsCOMObject
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call GetType() and inspect the [IsCOMObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.iscomobject.aspx) property